# Change the element in the XML Response in RestAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-web-api, xml-parsing

I am calling a third party API from the Rest AP I am creating. The third party API always returns in XML and it looks like

```
 <prj:prj uri="https://bh.org/api/v2/prj/V51" lid="V51" xmlns:udf="http://ge.com/ri/userdefined" xmlns:ri="http://ge.com/ri" xmlns:file="http://ge.com/ri/file" xmlns:prj="http://ge.com/ri/prj">
 <name>fgfgfg</name>
 <res uri="https://bh.org/api/v2/res/19"/>
 <udf:type name="cis"/>
 <udf:field type="String" name="ST">Cli</udf:field>
 <udf:field type="String" name="CPN">TestName</udf:field>
 <udf:field type="Numeric" name="No">1</udf:field>
 <udf:field type="String" name="CA">Do not know</udf:field>
 <udf:field type="String" name="Cto">Me</udf:field>
 <udf:field type="String" name="Site">GT</udf:field>
 </prj:prj>
```

Here I should just change the name from fgfgfg to ABCD and send the entire XML as the response. I am trying the below code

```
    var new_Name = "ABCD";
    var response_LabURL = client_LabName.GetAsync(clarity_URL).Result;
    string responseString_LabURL = response_LabURL.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    XDocument new_doc = XDocument.Parse(responseString_LabURL);
    var name_element = new_doc.Elements("name").Single();
    name_element.Value = new_Name;
    return Ok(new_doc);
```

But this throws error like `ExceptionMessage":"Sequence contains no elements","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"‌​,"StackTrace":" at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource]`

Comment: You should call `new_doc.Root.Elements("name")` on root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
XDocument xdc = XDocument.Load(YourXMLFile);
xdc.Descendants("name").FirstOrDefault().Value = "ABCD";
```

Now your object xdc is changed. You can care to save it.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for me:

```
var name_element = new_doc.Root.Elements("name").Single();
name_element.Value = "new name";
```

Please note I am using `Root` here.

Or try like this:

```
var name_element = new_doc.Descendants("name").Single();
name_element.Value = "new name";
```

Note, [Single()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.110).aspx) will throw exception if there are no elements in sequence!